# How to install PyV8 in windows10 platform by python3+?

Tags: python-3.x, pyv8

python version is python3.6.5, and i want to install PyV8 in windows 10.

i have got two files, such as PyV8.py, _PyV8.pyd. and put them into site-packages on my computer.
but, there are some mistakes:

```
>>> import PyV8 Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "D:\software\python\lib\site-packages\PyV8.py", line 32, in <module> import _PyV8 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_PyV8'
```

i have tried lot's of ways to solve them, but usless.

thx a lot ~